# Slim Framework - PDO object created but seems not inside the scope

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, slim

I get this error when I try to test my codes.

> Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ........

Below is my codes :

> ConnectionStrings.php

```
<?php
    $config = require dirname(__FILE__).'../../Configs/Local.php'; 

    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db   = 'CWW_SecurityDB';
    $user = $config['db']['user'];
    $pass = $config['db']['password'];
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

?>
```

> Authentication.php (Related part)

```
<?php
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    require dirname(__FILE__).'../../../ConnectionStrings.php';

    $app -> group('/authentication', function(){
        $this ->  Get('/login',
        function($request, $response, $args)
        {
            $Username = $request->getQueryParams()['Username'];
            $Password = $request->getQueryParams()['Password'];

            $sql = 'CALL SEC.usp_GetSecurityUsers(:Username)';
            $stmt = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
            $stmt -> bindParam(':Username', $Username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> execute();
            .
            .
            . (just a try out on the codes)
```

The problem should lie in the line **$stmt = $pdo -> prepare($sql);**. However, I really could not figure it out after hours. I have read some other posts with similar issue suggesting that the $pdo is out of scope.. but how exactly is my $pdo out of scope in this case? Can someone please enlighten me. Thank you in advance guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, you don't have global variables automatically available in the function scope (more on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)). Inside the function, $pdo needs to either be defined or somehow made available. Few ways come to my mind:

- Using `global $pdo;` in the function start - very old-school and won't be generally preferred way by php professionals.
- Replacing `$pdo` with `$GLOBALS['pdo']` - pretty much the same thing, kind of PHP3 style :)
- Pass $pdo to the closure's scope:

  ```
    $app->group('/authentication', function() use ($pdo) {
        $this->Get('/login', function($request, $response, $args) use ($pdo) {
  ```
- Fetch $pdo through dependency container (Slim3 uses Pimple for that):

  ```
    // Store $pdo in DI container.
    $container = $app->getContainer();
    $container['database'] = $pdo;
    ...
    // Then inside route controller:
    $pdo = $this->get('database');
  ```

Comment: Thanks bro. It helps! :)

Comment: I've tried every single way above... but i'm still getting error 500 : Internal Server error.. any clue on that? hmm...

Comment: That can be anything from parse error down to missing Slim parameter. Could you share your code, e.g. i http://phpfiddle.org/?